# Detect overlapping events

Tags: sqlite, overlap

I have a table with events a user can enter:

```
event_id | title   | start               | end  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0        | title 1 | 2014-10-29 09:00:00 | 2014-10-29 09:30:00
1        | title 2 | 2014-10-29 09:15:00 | 2014-10-29 09:45:00
2        | title 3 | 2014-10-29 10:00:00 | 2014-10-29 10:30:00
2        | title 3 | 2014-10-29 11:00:00 | 2014-10-29 11:30:00
```

I want to return an additional column `conflict` in a `Cursor` if any event overlaps.

```
event_id | title   | start               | end                 | conflict
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        | title 1 | 2014-10-29 09:00:00 | 2014-10-29 09:30:00 | 1
1        | title 2 | 2014-10-29 09:15:00 | 2014-10-29 09:45:00 | 1
2        | title 3 | 2014-10-29 10:00:00 | 2014-10-29 10:30:00 | 0
2        | title 3 | 2014-10-29 11:00:00 | 2014-10-29 11:30:00 | 0
```

I'm trying to find the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict if there exists any other event that overlaps the current event:

```
SELECT *,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM events AS other
               WHERE other.event_id != events.event_id
                 AND other.end > events.start
                 AND other.start < events.end) AS conflict
FROM events
```