# MongoDB: detect all overlapping events (start/end dates)?

Tags: mongodb

For a **specific** event (with start/end date) I can [check if there is an overlapping event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26877645/678951).

How can I list **all** overlapping events?

E.g. for:

| ID | start | end | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-16 10:00 | 2023-08-16 12:00 |  |
| 2 | 2023-08-16 12:00 | 2023-08-16 14:00 |  |
| 3 | 2023-08-16 14:00 | 2023-08-16 16:00 |  |
| 4 | 2023-08-16 11:00 | 2023-08-16 14:00 | overlaps with 1 and 2 |
| 5 | 2023-08-16 12:30 | 2023-08-16 12:40 | overlaps with 2 and 4 |

Should either return all affected events: 1,2,4,5
Or the highest ID's that are causing the overlaps: 4,5

Note: the dates are actually date objects, but shown as string in this table.

In MySQL [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683625/detect-overlapping-events) is how I would do it:

```
SELECT *,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM events AS other
               WHERE other.event_id < events.event_id
                 AND other.end > events.start
                 AND other.start < events.end) AS conflict
FROM events
```

How to achieve something similar in MongoDB?

Comment: what did you try? why the linked answer doesn't work for you? how you decide #5 overlaps #2 and not the other way round ?

Comment: The linked answer is useful if I want to check if there are e.g. overlapping events for event #1. I am looking for a single command that returns all of them, similar to SQL. Determine which one overlaps? Highest ID, see original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for a similar query is using `$lookup`:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "events",
      let: {id: "$ID", start: "$start",  end: "$end"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
                {$lt: ["$ID", "$$id"]},
                {$lt: ["$start", "$$end"]},
                {$gt: ["$end", "$$start"]}
        ]}}}
      ],
      as: "conflicts"
  }},
  {$match: {"conflicts.0": {$exists: true}}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, ID: 1, notes: "$conflicts.ID"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KeZEUSSJtjA)

Comment: Thanks! However the playground shows only #5 (overlap with 2 and 4). It should also list #4 (overlaps with 1 and 2). You mention it only checks a specific type of overlapping? See the linked post, all types of overlap have the same condition: `Sother < Eorig && Eother > Sorig` (use `<=` or `>=` to your liking)

Comment: Perfect. The 2nd example worked. But, the 1st can as well if you fix the match. It should be `{ $gt: [ "$end", "$$start" ] }, { $lt: [ "$start", "$$end" ] }` (similar to the SQL example). This covers all 4 types of overlap, see diagram in linked post.

Comment: You are right. updated the answer accordingly

Comment: great. For others visiting this solution, can you update the playground accordingly? And small typo: confilcts should be conflicts.